# Neo4J : Proper way to delete relationship?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Here's my nodes :

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Index(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    private String id;

    @Relationship(type = "LIKE")
    private Collection<Pattern> likedPatterns;
    ...
}


@NodeEntity
public class Pattern {
    @Id
    @Index(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = UuidStrategy.class)
    private String id;
    
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "LIKE", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<User> likes;
    ...
}
```

I try to delete relationship between user and pattern :

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void deleteLikedPattern(String patternId, Long authId) {
    User user = userRepository.findByAuthId(authId);
    user.getLikedPatterns().removeIf(p -> p.getId().equals(patternId));
    userRepository.save(user);
    
}
```

In the begining user has 2 pattern. On debug I can see that patternId is found in pattern collection, and corresponding pattern is removed from the list.
Then the save() is done, and I got no error. But if I check in DB, pattern and user are still linked, relationship is still here.

I tried solution on this post [Neo4j OGM how to delete relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391230/neo4j-ogm-how-to-delete-relationship)  which works. Which means that if I want to delete a relationship, I have to delete association in both entities list :

- delete pattern from user pattern's collection
- delete user from pattern user's collection)

  which is a little tedious...

And in many other thread asking for same problem, people seems not to suggest to delete association on both sides.
My question is : do I HAVE to delete association on both sides, or should it work by just removing pattern from user's favorites list?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no need to fully explain your relationship mappings in both classes of not needed. 
(Personal note: From an architectural point of view bidirectional dependencies between classes are something I would try to avoid.)

The answer is that you only need to remove it at the "leading" end. This is your `User`. In the moment you persist the `user` the relationship will get removed because Neo4j-OGM a) sees the modification and b) cannot reach the cut off node to traverse back to the `user` and re-create it in the same process.

Some additional notes: There should not even exist a repository for `Pattern` if the example above sees the `User` as an aggregate root. So persisting a `Pattern` always requires to persist a related `User`. As I can see this is a little bit more complicated in your current domain model because you are using m:n (many to many) mapping. The idea of Spring Data is to give you the ability to think and work in DDD (domain driver design). I suggest to read this article http://udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/ and/or other ones on many to many with DDD.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer but I'm not sure that I understand what you mean : "The answer is that you only need to remove it at the "leading" end. This is your User. In the moment you persist the user the relationship will get removed " -> I think this is exactly what I do but this is not working, that's my problem :)

Comment: About Pattern persisting, I didn't show the whole entities, just the parts that seems relevant for my problem, but a pattern is much more than that (as well for the User)

Comment: Is that possible that the `Pattern` can get found through other relationships (ignoring the directions) from the `User`? Generally speaking Neo4j-OGM travers all "reachable" nodes in the graph from the object/node you want to save/update.

Comment: actually there's many relationships between a user and a Pattern : user can own the pattern, can like it, can add it in his favorites. I'm new to neo4J but I thought that what I've shown above is the classic way to define a relationship, specifing both ends of the relationship in corresponding entities, one which is "Incoming" and the other "Outcoming". Specificity here is that, as you said, this is a "ManyToMany" as a user can like many pattern, and a pattern can be liked by many users, and I must be able to display those informations on different part of my app

Comment: In this case I suggest using a (very) finite depth for the saving like `0`. That will result in a `repo.save(user, 0)`. I am yet not sure if this even touches the relationships or ignores it. But give it a try before I find time.